# Redirect to a HTML page in Vue JS

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm using `Vue.js`. I want to have a redirection from my vue component to a basic `HTML` page. I can't convert that to a vue component as it is a License Agreement. Is there a way in vue so that I can have a `HTML` page and redirect to that in a new tab?

```
<a href="<link to html>">License Agreement</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

That simple
Just have that html in **public** folder.
You can redirect it just like how you have mentioned above!

```
<a href="<link to html">Link</a>
```